# canvas is not merging and resulting in showing only background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have create 2 canvas, load two differnt image and I want to merge both canvas and then display it as image in `<div id="test"></div>` tag.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>canvas to image</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas id="card_canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas id="card_canvas2" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="canvasToImage()">canvas to image</button>
<script>
    var img1 = new Image();
        img1.src = "images/img1.jpg";
    var cuimg;
    function canvasToImage(){
        var canvass1 = document.getElementById("card_canvas");
        var canvass2 = document.getElementById("card_canvas2");
        var ctx1 = canvass1.getContext('2d');
        var ctx2 = canvass2.getContext('2d');
        ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        cuimg = new Image();
        cuimg.onload = function(){
            ctx2.drawImage(cuimg, 7, 92);
        }
        cuimg.src = "images/img2.jpg";
        ctx1.drawImage(canvass2, 0, 0);
        var imgdata = canvass1.toDataURL('image/png');
        var mergeimg = document.createElement("img");
        mergeimg.src = imgdata;
        document.getElementById("test").appendChild(mergeimg);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is img1.jpg:

[image: img1.jpg]

Here is img2.jpg:

[image: img2.jpg]

This code ends up in displaying only background image:

[image: result]

I am expecting:

[image: expected]

Comment: You are calling ctx1.drawImage(canvas2) and canvas1.toDataURL() while you still didn't draw the image on canvas2 : You correctly use the image's onload event before drawing it to the canvas, which makes this operation asynchronous. You need to call the logical following after this operation has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by simply setting following style on canvas2:

```
<canvas id="card_canvas2" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"></canvas>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jkjqd7gz/

Comment: This will only overlap the canvas and display it, and I will not be able to save it as image.

Comment: In your  fiddle, doing a right click and on viewing image it only shows lee9 image, but I want it to merge both yellow background and lee9 image and then make it an image and then display it. So basically, when right clicking and viewing the image it should show yellow background and lee9 logo onverlapping it.

Comment: Please check this link [link] (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been fiddling with your code a bit, and I think I've figured out the issue. javascript has a funny execution order at times that most people aren't aware of. Your onload lambda function is causing some of the issues your experiencing. Basically, you need to move your ctx1.drawImage(canvass2, 0, 0); line inside your lambda function just after ctx2.drawImage(cuimg, 7, 92); To understand what I mean open your code and hit the canvas to image button twice. The first time populates both canvasses, the second time puts the contents of canvass2 onto canvass1. I could probably explain exactly what's happening in terms of order of execution, but the explanation involves some difficult to understand concepts regarding parallelism, swap buffers, and race conditions.

To put it in a nutshell, whatever function you call ctx2.drawImage in, you need to then follow it with ctx1.drawImage. Honestly though, the best way to make composite images is to create a sprite class that stores an image, its postion, and layer information if desired. Then use a dynamic array to store the sprites. Always clear the canvas every time before you draw on it and loop through the contents of your arrays drawing each sprite in layer order on its respective canvass. Finally, I would use one set of functions to populate the canvas and a second to merge them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>canvas to image</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas id="card_canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas id="card_canvas2" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="popCanvas()">Populate Canvasses</button>
<button onclick="canvasToImage()">Canvas Combine</button>
<script>
    var img1 = new Image();
        img1.src = "images/img1.jpg";
    var cuimg = new Image();
    var canvass1 = document.getElementById("card_canvas");
    var canvass2 = document.getElementById("card_canvas2");
    function popCanvas(){
        var ctx1 = canvass1.getContext('2d');
        var ctx2 = canvass2.getContext('2d');
        ctx1.clear()
        ctx2.clear()
        ctx1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        cuimg.onload = function(){
            ctx2.drawImage(cuimg, 7, 92);
        }
        cuimg.src = "images/img2.jpg";
    }
    function canvasToImage(){
        var ctx1 = canvass1.getContext('2d');
        var ctx2 = canvass2.getContext('2d');
        ctx1.drawImage(canvass2, 0, 0);
        var imgdata = canvass1.toDataURL('image/png');
        var mergeimg = document.createElement("img");
        mergeimg.src = imgdata;
        document.getElementById("test").appendChild(mergeimg);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You caught the problem, but there is a requirement on my side to achive this with single button click.

Comment: @user123456987 is there a requirement that you draw your image to the second canvas in an onload function?

Comment: No. Image can be drawn on the canvas 1. That is First drawing the img1.jpg in canvas1 and then drawing img2.jpg also in canvas1. This could be done. But the final image should be Img1 in background and img2 in foreground overlapping img1. I am caring about the final image, not canvas or number of canvas.

Comment: @user123456987 okay, that makes things simpler, canvasses always display the last thing drawn on top, so you just need to draw the background image on your canvas first, then the foreground image. That's kind of what I was getting at about using an array with layer numbers, then draw the lowest layer(background or 0) first. After they're drawn you just do what you were intending and save the canvas contents to an image file.